# How do I make room in my inventory?

Tags: the-witcher

So I found this rad new axe that I wanted to equip, so I dropped my old one and went to pick the new one up.

Unfortunately I just got an "Inventory Full" status.

So I dropped a few more items from my inventory... and then a few more, and then a few more.

But whenever I try to pick up the axe the game still refuses because my inventory is full.

**How much do I need to drop before I can pick up a new weapon?**

Edit: The plot thickens. I tried dropping and picking up my Steel Sword and old Axe, and was able to reequip both without issue. Is there something special about the Temerian Iron Axe I'm trying to pick up now?

Comment: There are axes for the small weapon slot, and axes for the heavy weapon slot. Not sure which one the Temerian Iron Axe is for, but did you try both the small and heavy slot?

Comment: In the first witcher game, there's no point to using anything other than swords. The witcher combat styles don't work with any other weapons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't carry weapons in your "inventory" where other items like herbs, potions, books, and quest items sit. Instead, you can only carry weapons in the large equipment slots pictured; you have a Silver Sword slot, two Heavy Weapon slots (which can hold Steel Swords, as well as weapons like axes and maces) and a Light Weapon slot that can hold daggers, torches, etc.

You can only carry one in each slot. Fortunately, you'll *almost never* want to use anything other than a Steel or Silver sword. Later in the game, you might want to carry two steel swords with different properties, but early on, just hold on to whatever short and heavy weapon you'll be able to sell for the most money when you get to a merchant. They have no other use or value.

<sub>(At the very very end of the game, you'll get an armor upgrade that adds a second Short Weapon slot. This is 100% completely and totally useless.)</sub>